# How to transfer photos wirelessly without losing file date and time

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, photos, file-transfer, date-and-time

I want to quickly wirelessly transfer photos off an Android (Kit Kat) device.  The catch: I don't want to lose the file dates/times during the transfer.  Specifically, I am **not** talking about the EXIF date/time; I am talking about the actual file date/time.  I organize my images by file timestamp (aka datestamp) and having the file timestamp change during the transfer prevents this simply and effective technique.  This task is trivial to accomplish with a wire, but I have been unable to find a wireless solution.

I prefer a solution that can be performed without any internet access, but am open to all solutions.

**What I've Tried**

- I tried using ShareIt.  Datestamps are changed.  FAIL.
- I tried using SuperBeam with the experimental option to maintain timestamps enabled.  Datestamps are changed.  FAIL.
- I tried using Google Drive.  Datestamps are changed.  Internet access required.  DOUBLE FAIL.

***Does anyone know what will work?***

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "transfer photos off an Android" to "transfer from android to pc" i use a pc software to reconstruct the file-date from the exifdate (exiftools)

for the other direction "from pc to android" i insert the android-s sd-card into the pc so the pc can set the file-modification date.

On my android-4.2 and android-4.4 devices the android-os prevents the manual seting of a file-timestamp so transfering to android device via wifi will not work (at least not with my android devices).

[update 2017-02-21]

i have programmed a batch with [exiftools](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) :

```
 exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal>FileModifyDate" -ignoreMinorErrors -overwrite_original -r -ext .jpg .
```

meaning: copy for all *.jpg in current dir and their subdirs: exif-DateTimeOriginal to FileModifyDate

Comment: Thanks.  What software pc software do you use (regarding your first sentence)?

Comment: I have update my answer